# R: How to separate and add numerical values separated by ";" (maxed out memory problem)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have 5000 rows of up to 2000 values separated by ";" which are currently stuffed into a single column. I would like to separate them, add them and throw away the original column. Problem: I max out memory quickly. Currently using more than 60GB RAM. What is a good way to deal with this?

So far I have:

## Option 1: Dplyr

```
#Not every line has the same number of values
MaxNumSemiColon=2001 #Max amount

    df %>%
        separate(dose_close, sep=";",
        remove = TRUE,
        into = paste0("dummy",1: MaxNumSemiColon),
        convert = TRUE,
        fill = "right")%>%
        rowwise() %>% 
        mutate(dose_close = sum(c_across(dummy1:paste0("dummy",numSemiColon)),na.rm = TRUE))%>%
        select(-contains("dummy"))
```

## Option 2: Data.table

```
  setDT(df)[, paste0("dose_close", 1:numSemiColon) := tstrsplit(value, ";", type.convert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)]
  temp<-temp[,-1]
  temp<-temp%>% rowSums() %>% as.data.frame() %>% set_colnames("dose_close")
  df$dose_close<-NULL
  df<-cbind(df,temp) #Bind dose_close
```

NB: I saw data.table::fread has sep2=";" which would be ideal but does anyone know when it might be available?

Comment: Try using `fread` on the pasted column?

Comment: Can you also share whether the number of values per row in the semicolon delimited column is consistent? You mention 'up to 2000 values separated by ";"' so I'm assuming that some rows may have fewer than 2000 values, or perhaps even no values or `NA`.

Comment: why could you just not do `rowSums(read.csv(text = df$dose_close, fill = TRUE, sep = ";"), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @Onyambu, they could. They might have to use the same "trick" that I had to use with `fread` to force `read.csv` to read the correct number of columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason you should have trouble using `fread` directly on the pasted column. The problems you might encounter for data this size is more likely to be incorrect detection of the number of resulting columns, and not maxing out on memory.

Here's some sample data to play with:

```
library(data.table)
n <- 5000
set.seed(1)
vals_row <- sample(2000, n, TRUE)
DT <- data.table(ID = 1:n, 
                 vals = sapply(vals_row, function(x) 
                   paste(sample(100, x, TRUE), collapse = ";")))
DT[sample(n, n*.05), vals := NA]
```

Reading the data with `fread`.

```
system.time({test <- fread(text = c(paste0("V", sequence(max(vals_row)), collapse = ";"),
                                    DT$vals), sep = ";", fill = TRUE, header = TRUE)})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.728   0.036   0.263 
dim(test)
# [1] 5000 2000
test[1:10, 1:10]
#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#  1: 45 42  6 57 70 24 12 15 11  68
#  2: 94 47 12 46 33 80 66 12 93  89
#  3:  6 21 59 16 20 30 57  9 67 100
#  4:  6 39 59 87 83 23 24 12 63  62
#  5: 78 90 34 26 31 51 60 41 36  82
#  6: 68 76 53 16  7 64 18 34 49  56
#  7: 33 94 87 80 25 95 70 42 53  39
#  8: 77 96 55 43 61 37 11  9 48  94
#  9: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
# 10:  9 66 44 31 83 30 45 92 17  24

bench::mark(fread(text = c(paste0("V", sequence(max(vals_per_row)), collapse = ";"),
  DT$vals), sep = ";", fill = TRUE, header = TRUE))[, c("min", "median", "mem_alloc")]
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#        min   median mem_alloc
#   <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:byt>
# 1    250ms    250ms     114MB
```

For reference, I did try `fread` directly without making the fake column names first, but the guessing of the maximum number of columns failed. This is [a known issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2727), and a workaround is to insert a line at the start with the desired number of columns. If the number of columns in each row is consistent, this shouldn't be a problem.

Once you have `test`, you can just do:

```
rowSums(test, na.rm = TRUE)
```

to get your desired output.

This, and the other options shared here have been benchmarked at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/97243716dd7a0c11f395820a28b92e10).

---

Another good alternative would be to use `dstrsplit` or `mstrsplit` from the "iotools" package:

```
library(iotools)
vals <- max(vals_row)
# dstrsplit
dstrsplit(DT$vals, col_types = rep("integer", vals), sep = ";")
# mstrsplit
mstrsplit(DT$vals, sep = ";", type = "integer", ncol = vals)
```

Comment: And, by the way, *works on my 4GB RAM Chromebook* ™ :-p

Comment: Thank you very much. You still have to guess at the max number of columns though, no? I don't really know what the maxval could actually be. So it works well if I get it right but if I don't it chews up 60GB of ram and I have to kill it. Its there a nuance I'm missing?

Comment: @HCAI, add a step like: `max(stringi::stri_count_fixed(DT$vals, ";"), na.rm = TRUE) + 1`. Shouldn't take a lot of time or RAM.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your work on this. Philosophically it makes a lot more sense now too!

Comment: @HCAI, no problem. If you want to explore further, there's also the "iotools" package. I'd probably recommend looking at `dstrsplit` (something like `dstrsplit(DT$vals, col_types = rep("integer", 2000), sep = ";")` should work). I generally use `fread` because of the flexibility (automatic type detection, for example) and speed, but as we can see here, there are some cases that require workarounds that probably won't be required with "iotools". Also, "iotools" does have multiple `sep` arguments, so I'm not sure whether that would help you with your data at the source.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do something like this?
Should be low on memory usage since he only splits one string at a time and then returns the value as a double. Works on my 32GB RAM computer.

```
split_sum <- function(string){
string %>%
stringr::str_split(';') %>%
magrittr::extract2(1) %>%
as.double() %>%
sum()
}
tibble::tibble(dose_close = rep(paste0(runif(2000), collapse = ';'), 5000)) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(
    dose_close = purrr::map_dbl(dose_close, split_sum)
)
# A tibble: 5,000 x 1
   dose_close
        <dbl>
 1      1002.
 2      1002.
 3      1002.
 4      1002.
 5      1002.
 6      1002.
 7      1002.
 8      1002.
 9      1002.
10      1002.
# ... with 4,990 more rows
```

Comment: This works and you don't have to worry about a potentially varying number of columns per row. +1

Comment: In case you're interested, I've benchmarked this at https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/97243716dd7a0c11f395820a28b92e10.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use 'read_delim()`from the "readr" package.

```
#test data
test<-c("a;b;c;d;e", "1;2;3;4;5", 'r;s;t;v')
df<-data.frame(test, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(readr)
read_delim(df$test, delim=";", col_names = FALSE)


# A tibble: 3 x 5
 X1    X2    X3    X4    X5   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     b     c     d     e    
2 1     2     3     4     5    
3 r     s     t     v     NA
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks ideal. I copied exactly as-is and it gives me "Error: `file` must be a string, raw vector or a connection."

Comment: I mean I copied your example and it gives me that error with your test data.. Strange no?

Comment: Other than the possible "stringsAsFactors" correction, I can't explain the error.

Comment: In case you're interested, I've benchmarked this at https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/97243716dd7a0c11f395820a28b92e10. I'm not a regular `readr` user, so I'm not sure if the steps I took were the best for making this approach work with my sample data. +1 for the alternative.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Nice work. I expected the data table to be the fastest.  Readr is similar style but quicker than the corresponding base functions and with some improvements.

Comment: @Dave2e, there were some unexpected things for me. I had to specify column types because the last few columns were being coerced to character. At any rate, I know base R's `read.table` benefits from specifying as much as possible--I don't know whether this holds true for `readr::read_delim` as well.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Thank you very much for benchmarking these for us. I've ended up using fun_a5 because it was the fastest